# How Visual Studio 2010 manage virtual users in load test?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, load-testing, performance-testing

I have a load run with 150 concurrent users. however, after test execution I switched to virtual users activity chart, I saw virtual users with big id like 1205, with the id grows when test lasts longer. Shouldn't it be 1-150 or 0-149?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the **Percentage of new users** greater than zero then you should expect the user id to continually increase throughout the test. The number of users will be 150, given the details in the question, but their identification numbers increase as each new user starts.

The effect of the user id can be seen in the **Detail** page of the load test results. Each horizontal line corresponds to one user id. When **Percentage of new users** is zero then you will see multiple tests executed for the same user. With 150 users there will be 150 horizontal lines each with multiple tests. When **Percentage of new users** is 100 then you will see a long diagonal running from bottom left corner to top right corner made of horizontal lines but with only one test on each horizontal line, ie only one test per user.